# Register UnifiedAgentConfiguration Azure Migrate

Tags: azure, powershell, migrate

I am trying to install Unified Agent for Azure Migrate remotely following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-migrate-physical-virtual-machines#install-the-mobility-service

But running this command:

```bsh
UnifiedAgentConfigurator.exe  /CSEndPoint <replication appliance IP address> /PassphraseFilePath <Passphrase File Path>
```

results in

```bsh
Starting silent configuration.
Running configuration for VmWare
Starting registration for VmWare platform
CS endpoint for registration - 10.10.1.7
Passphrase file for registration - c:\Temp\passphrase.txt
Preparing for registration
Invalid configuration server IP or connection passphrase provided.
```

My passphrase.txt file just contains the passphrase strng.

When running UnifiedAgentConfigurator.exe interactively and adding the same IP and passphrase, configuration succeeds as expected.

Is the passphrase file supposed to be formated in some undocumented way or is encoding of the text tile important?

Answer (score 1):

Encoding did it.

```bsh
'MyPassPhrase' | out-file C:\Temp\passphrase.txt -NoNewLine -encoding default
```